# How should I handle individual ID access in ASP Core authorization?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-middleware

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction, or knows of a good article on the following situation?

I have an ASP Core site which has granular access levels to individual DB records that are set up by their 'local' super user. From the various articles I've read online, I'm getting the impression this should be handled by the Resource Based Authorization Policies. Let's take this example:

```
//Delete Generic foo
public ActionResult Delete(int id){
    //Deletes foo record based on Id, 
    //but only if the user has been given permission to the record with id == x
}
```

So, I have an array of all foo IDs associated with the user, stored in a single claim.

```
"FooIds" : ["1", "3", "5"]
```

Perhaps I'm miles off the right track and this should be handled in a completely different way. It's taking a lot of willpower not to just perform the check in the function, so how should this be handled? I feel this must be fairly common.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I wouldn't do that in a claim. Just do the check in the function. The problem with using the claim is that the claims get really big and browsers have problems with that. Also, they can be out of date.

Comment: I was of the impression that MS were heavily against authorization style actions being handled outside of the authorization middleware? The closest I could find was the Resource Based Authorization which is part of the middleware but handled in side of the function.

Comment: Ok--in aspnet core, you can write a custom policy handler https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html You can inject your database context into the handler as well.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise I could inject the context, this could be perfect!

Comment: Unfortunately, a problem with that approach is that you don't have access to the controller parameter in the handler without going through actionContext, which I feel for the task at hand is very convoluted.

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html#accessing-mvc-request-context-in-handlers Seems like that is the way to do it. I don't know what you mean by convoluted. Looks like you can access the route data pretty easily